# JsTree custom contextmenu in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jstree

I try to use jstree control in my TypeScript code for an angularjs application. I use jstree typings and jstree.directive to show a tree. Everything works to the point when I need to handle menu item click and call for the base method. Inside of my action there is no "this" (contextmenu) scope. Any suggestions?

```
class MapTreeViewController {

    mapTreeView: JSTree;

vm.mapTreeView = $('#jstree').jstree(
     {
         'core': { 'data': items },
         'plugins': ['themes', 'ui', 'contextmenu'],
          'contextmenu': {
            'items': function(node:any) {
              var vmNode = this;
              return {
                'rename': { // rename menu item
                  'label': 'Rename',
                  'action': function(obj) {
                    this.rename(obj);
                  }
                }
              };
            }
          }
        });
}
```

Somewhere inside of a method.

[image: Custom context menu item action]

Comment: @Okazari, yes typo is there but "this" anyways is null and there are no methods for a null object. Going further "this" is suppose to be a contextmenu scope, which is not angular's view $scope. Angular's $scope doesn't have "rename" method, but "contextmenu" does.

Comment: I think we need some more code here to investigate. Actually this probably have nothing to do with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not an instance - take a look at the original function to see how to obtain an instance:
https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/src/jstree.contextmenu.js#L84

```
"action" : function (data) {
    var inst = $.jstree.reference(data.reference),
    ...
```

Comment: This is how I ended up, opened your source and used code from there. Also had to fix typings for TypeScript, edit method doesn't have a call_back function parameter. Although edit method doesn't work nicely with Chrome browser. Input folds and it's impossible to see what I edit, that is an area I will need to look into and hopefully PR you changes. Thank you Ivan, really amazing job on this tree control.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. `edit()` has a callback param if you need it - it was added recently. As for Chrome - I have not noticed an issue - file an issue on github when you have the time, so that I can reproduce and fix. Thank you.